# Send automated mass, uniquely tailored messages to a list of participants (is it possible?)

Tags: microsoft-teams

My company wants to conduct a pilot to see if providing doctors with certain risk information about their patients would help them make better decisions.  Before we build a full scale app, we just want to determine if the information is useful to doctors, it helps patients, and if generating the data and getting it to doctors is even feasible.  Unfortunately, due to institutional data security and privacy rules, I have to use Microsoft Teams messaging to test this.  Otherwise, I'd use Microsoft Access VBA, loop through a list of emails, and send the tailored information that way.  However, because I won't be able to easily encrypt emails like this (and it prone to people forgetting - unless there's a way to set up encryption from MS Access VBA) I can't use MS Access/Outlook.

So bottom line, say I have a dataset with 20 emails/Teams contact information of doctors, along with unique medical information about 1 of their patients.  Aside from copying and pasting the data into a message, and sending it in Microsoft Teams for each doctor, is this a more automated way to do this? Think of this as sort of a Microsoft Teams mail merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Company communicator app template. Company Communicator is a custom Teams app that enables corporate teams to create and send messages intended for multiple teams or large number of employees over chat allowing organization to reach employees right where they collaborate. Please go through this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator).
Hope that answers your question!